# Bind same model to different schemas in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, binding, sqlalchemy

I want to create my model in two different databases (e.g., in Postgres and Redshift) with different shema names. E.g., in postgres i have schema *public*, and in redshift schema called *data*.

E.g., I have two engines:

```
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'bind1':    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'],
    'data'  'redshift+psycopg2://dbuser:pass@dbhost.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/mydb'
}
```

Here is a model:

```
class Campaign(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'campaign'
    #__bind_key__ = 'data'
    campaignid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    campaign_name = Column(String(120))
    smth = Column(BigInteger)
```

First, I tried to create declarative base and bind it explicitly (which works good but doesn't solve my problem 'cos I need to define model twice for each schema/engine):

```
engine = create_engine('redshift+psycopg2://dbuser:pass@dbhost.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/mydb')
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata = MetaData(bind=engine, schema='data')
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

I want to use same model and create it in different schemas on different DBs. So I can use ***bind_key*** to indicate which DB i want to use but also indicate different **schema names** for different DBs though.

Appreciate for any hints.